Finding a specific user's fork of a given repo
I'm trying to use the GitHub GraphQL API to solve the following problem. Suppose there is a repo alice/repo1 and another user bob. I want to find if bob has a fork of alice/repo1, and if so, what the name of this repo is. (It might not always be bob/repo1).
The closest I got was the following query, but I can't work out how to filter the results by owner:
query {
  repository(owner:"alice",name:"repo1") {
    forks(first:30) {
      nodes {
        nameWithOwner
        owner {
          login
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

